# Get prop value from div in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A working example of my problem can be found at:

https://codepen.io/RyanCRickert/pen/vYYQeaW

I am prop drilling a function two levels and passing that function along with an index to a rendered component.  When a name is submitted it renders a new component which shows the name and div which has an onClick (X).  I am trying to receive the index of where the name is located in the array which it lives so that I may splice it out when the button is clicked.

If I enter the name "Bob" for example, then click the div with the listener I can console log the event.target.  Using the above example I get `"<div class='person-item__X' value='0'>X</div>"` for event.target and undefined for event.target.value.  The value is being assigned as `<div onClick={props.removeName} class="person-item__X" value={props.value}>X</div>`.

Am I just unable to grab the value of a div in such a manor?  Or is there something that I am missing?  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these to your code

```
const PersonListItem = props => (
  <div class="person-item">
    <div class="person-item__name">{props.name}</div>
    <div onClick={() => props.removeName(props.value)} class="person-item__X" value={props.value}>X</div>
  </div>
);
```

Inside PeopleList replace this line

```
<PersonListItem key={index} name={person} value={index} removeName={(id) => props.removeName(id)} />
```

Inside TeamGenerator replace this line

```
<PeopleList people={this.state.names} removeName={(id) => this.handleRemoveName(id)} />
```

now in handleRemoveName you will recieve a **id** of the item on which X was clicked

```
handleRemoveName = id => {
    const currentArr = this.state.names;
    console.log(id);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, to grab the value inside this div, you should use `ref` API.

Your code should look like this:

TeamGenerator.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CustomModal from "./Modal";
import PeopleList from "./PeopleList";
import "./index.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Create a ref
    this.divTextRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      names: [],
      selectedName: ""
    };
  }

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      selectedName: ""
    });
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  };

  handleRemoveName = index => {
    // Get your name and index this way
    console.log("Your text: ", this.divTextRef.current.innerHTML);
    console.log("Your index: ", index);
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const currentNames = this.state.names;
    if (this.state.name)
      currentNames.push(
        this.state.name[0].toUpperCase() + this.state.name.slice(1)
      );

    this.setState({
      name: "",
      names: currentNames
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <CustomModal
          selectedName={this.state.selectedName}
          closeModal={this.handleCloseModal}
        />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Add name:
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.name}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <div className="people-list-container">
          <PeopleList
            people={this.state.names}
            removeName={this.handleRemoveName}
            upperRef={this.divTextRef} // Pass the ref down from your Component tree
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

PeopleList.js

```
import React from "react";
import PersonListItem from "./PersonListItem";

export default class PeopleList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="people-container">
        <div className="people-title">List of people</div>
        <div className="people-list">
          {this.props.people.length === 0 ? (
            <div className="people-item">
              <span>No people added</span>
            </div>
          ) : (
            this.props.people.map((person, index) => (
              <PersonListItem
                key={index}
                name={person}
                value={index}
                removeName={() => this.props.removeName(index)} // Passing index to the removeName function of Parent
                upperRef={this.props.upperRef} // Continue passing it down to PersonListItem
              />
            ))
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

PersonListItem.js

```
import React from "react";

const PersonListItem = props => (
  <div className="person-item">
    <div ref={props.upperRef} className="person-item__name"> // Use the passed ref
      {props.name}
    </div>
    <div
      onClick={props.removeName}
      className="person-item__X"
      value={props.value}
    >
      X
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default PersonListItem;
```

The `div` node does not have the value like `input`, so you can not grab it by your old way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look into this as refs are not things I have worked with much.